# How to do matrix-scalar multiplication in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

What would be the best way to multiply a matrix by a scalar in TensorFlow?
I simply want to scale up the matrix by some scalar value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can multiply a matrix (or any other tensor) by a scalar using the *element-wise* [`tf.multiply()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/multiply) operation, which implicitly broadcasts its arguments to match sizes:

```
x = tf.constant([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
y = tf.multiply(x, 2.0)

sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(y)
# ==> [[2.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.0]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess also works for any a single variable tensor that is not 2.0 right?

Comment: Sure! You can do `z = tf.Variable(some_scalar); y = tf.mul(x , z)` (or `z = tf.constant(...)` etc.).

Comment: Renamed to tf.multiply() in TensorFlow 1.0. Also note that there is a function tf.scalar_mul().

Answer (score 4):

very simple:

**scalar * matrix**

TensorFlow converts that to tf.multiply and broadcasts everything.

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent variants:

```
x = tf.constant([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]]
y1 = tf.scalar_mul(-1.0, x)
y2 = tf.multiply(-1.0, x)
y3 = -1.0 * x
```

Output:

```
sess.run(y1)
array([[-1., -0.],
       [-0., -1.]], dtype=float32)

sess.run(y2)
array([[-1., -0.],
       [-0., -1.]], dtype=float32)

sess.run(y3)
array([[-1., -0.],
       [-0., -1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scalar_mul(scalar, x)
```

Multiplies a scalar times a `Tensor` or `IndexedSlices` object.

Intended for use in gradient code which might deal with `IndexedSlices`
  objects, which are easy to multiply by a scalar but more expensive to
  multiply with arbitrary tensors.

Args:
    scalar: A 0-D scalar `Tensor`. Must have known shape.
    x: A `Tensor` or `IndexedSlices` to be scaled.

Returns:
    `scalar * x` of the same type (`Tensor` or `IndexedSlices`) as `x`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation. You can use `tf.math.scalar_mul` which will take the scalar value as first parameter and the tensor as the second one.

That means your code will be

```py
x = tf.constant([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
y = tf.math.scalar_mul(2.0, x)

sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(y)
```

It is not recommended to use numpy operations within complicated operations in case you are using Tensorflow on Keras for models training. It is imperative to use only tensor operators.

For more details and documentation about tensor operators. It is a best practice to check : [Tensorflow math module official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math) it has sufficient functions that look like numpy operators.